# Invalid VERSION for Request. Only 1.1.0 (GetCapabilities) supported

Tags: qgis, wfs

QGIS 2.13.2-Lyon

I`m new to QGIS and I'm struggling with getting data from a WFS connection:

```
http://sdi.fish.govt.nz/sdi/mapserver.wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&v‌​ersion=1.1.0&
```

The error I get is: 
`Exception: Invalid VERSION for Request. Only 1.1.0 (GetCapabilities) supported`

[image: connection example]

Based on my search, this is an issue other users encounter but I haven't been able to follow any of the solutions offered. Ultimately I want to:
a) get a list of layers available with this WFS connection b) download layers off this list.

My work flow is:

- Layer
- Add Layer
- Add WFS Layer
- New
- add connection `http://sdi.fish.govt.nz/sdi/mapserver.wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&v‌​ersion=1.1.0`
- name connection `NABIS`
- OK
- Connect

`Exception: Invalid VERSION for Request. Only 1.1.0 (GetCapabilities) supported`

Comment: I read that error as saying "You forgot to specify a VERSION".  The [doc](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html) says the parameter is REQUIRED.

Comment: That is the connection supplied by NABIS `http://www.nabis.govt.nz/NabisContent.aspx?ContentGroupId=1`. I have tried lots of edits to it, including specifying a version but thought I would offer the recommended url for my stack exchange question

Comment: `http://sdi.fish.govt.nz/sdi/mapserver.wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.1.0` works as expected.  Specifications are the heart and soul of web mapping.  You must be willing to follow the API as published.

Comment: This sounds promising but the link you provided and the equivalent one I wrote are not working.. Maybe my approach is wrong, in QGIS: Layer, Add Layer, Add WFS Layer, New, add url as above, add arbitary name, connect and I get the same error message as in my question.  What have you done differently?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with additional details--maybe including screen shots of what you are doing.  I tried the WFS connection Vince references above and it works for me as well.

Comment: Have you double-checked that the WFS you are trying to connect to is not at an earlier, or later version, than 1.1.0 (which the message says is the only one supported)?

Comment: Vince's URL abbreviates to the one in the screenshot, sorry can't post another screenshot because my reputation is too low but does that suffice?

Comment: I have tried lots of iterations and run all checks that occurred to me before asking the question.....

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the version of QGIS you are using.  The fact that the screenshot has part of the URL you specified, but not all, indicates that there is a fundamental problem unrelated to the URL.

Comment: Better? the abbreviation only removes the getcapabilities,

Comment: When you guys are saying the WFS is working are you getting a list of shapes and not an error when you use the connection? I have got this far with alternate programs but not in QGIS

Comment: The version parameter is NOT required for any OGC web service GetCapabilities request.  The request without version parameter works for me: http://sdi.fish.govt.nz/sdi/mapserver.wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities& it returns a version="1.1.0" response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes definitely from a bug in QGIS. I followed your example and configured QGIS 2.12.0 to use WFS service with URL

```
http://sdi.fish.govt.nz/sdi/mapserver.wfs?version=1.1.0
```

Then I used a local proxy server for capturing the request that QGIS was sending once the Connect button was pressed. This is the request:

```
http://sdi.fish.govt.nz/sdi/mapserver.wfs?version=1.1.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.0.0
```

QGIS is automatically adding &VERSION=1.0.0 to the end of the request. It does not help to include **&version=1.1.0** into the URL because the automatically added **&VERSION=1.0.0** is overriding it. You don't do anything wrong. Best you can do is to file a QGIS bug at https://hub.qgis.org/issues. Suggest them to add radio buttons 1.0.0/1.1.0/2.0.0 into the WFS server connection panel for selecting the WFS version to use. I am not sure if QGIS supports WFS 1.1.0 and 2.0.0, though.

In WFS 1.1.0 standard version is not mandatory in GetCapabilities. Actually, not even "service" seems to be as you can see from the XML schema

```
<xsd:element name="GetCapabilities" type="wfs:GetCapabilitiesType"/>
<xsd:complexType name="GetCapabilitiesType">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:extension base="ows:GetCapabilitiesType">
<xsd:attribute name="service" type="ows:ServiceType"
use="optional" default="WFS"/>
</xsd:extension>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

However, instead of relying on the defaults it would a robust client should add the explicit SERVICE= and VERSION= parameters. QGIS is doing the right thing otherwise but it should allow users to select the version instead of overriding it secretly into 1.0.0.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to not assume I was doing something wrong and actually addressing the question!